# Chrome save file dialogs stop working after an arbitrary period of time

Tags: google-chrome

I am afraid that I may be on an island with this one, but this is a real productivity killer for somebody who keeps three chrome windows open, each with multiple tabs, on separate monitors.

After an arbitrary period of time, typically ranging from a few hours to a few days, Chrome save-file dialogs stop opening.

Upon clicking something that would cause the save-file dialog to open, the window flickers, and nothing further happens.

I do have the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" option checked in Chrome's settings.

- I am using Windows 7 with the latest version of Chrome.
- I have tried uninstalling all extensions

Comment: Happening to me too. The only difference is that I can open 1 page and 1 file dialog, all file dialogs after the first one won't open.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you click anywhere on chrome after the windows flickers?
If you hear a 'beep' that means chrome has lost focus, or if the dialog box appears then disappears again when you try to click it, then this could be what happens to me too.

Sometimes the dialog box is opened in the background and you can't access it if the browser windows is maximized, I've seen this problem a lot and didn't find a solution for it, just work-arounds.

What I found:

1-Don't maximize the browser window and when you click a download link, the dialog box will be visible, you can click 'Alt' + 'Spacebar' then 'm' to move the dialog box with the arrows (actually you can click any arrow just once, then move the mouse and then left click when it's visible, that's much easier than the arrows)

What I use:

1-'[FileBox eXtender](http://www.hyperionics.com/files/)' or '[eXtra Buttons](http://www.xtrabuttons.com/)'

2-like before, don't maximize the browser, and when the dialog box appears click on 'Always on top' on the title bar.

Or if you like to keep the browser maximized like me, then use '[Always On Top Maker](http://www.fadsoft.net/AlwaysOnTopMaker.htm)' and simply press 'Ctrl' + 'Alt' + 't' to bring the dialog box on top. Btw this is a tiny utility, about 24 KB.

Sorry if there's anything that's not clear, English isn't my native language.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this next time it happens (should be within a workday or two!)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem very easily - just went to Google searched for Chrome and downloaded and installed it again. All me history, bookmarks and everything obviously stayed untouched just the core Chrome program files got overwritten which corrected whatever issue there was - well that's my theory but most important thing is that it works now, hope that helps you too!